# Kubernetes configuration with yaml anchors

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, yaml, kubectl

I have a `deployment.yaml` file and want to reuse the environment for all my deployments like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: beat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: beat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: beat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: beat
        image: myimage
        command: ["celery", "-A", "wsgi.celery", "beat"]
        env: &default
        - name: FIRST_ENV
          value: my-value
        - name: SECOND_ENV
          value: another-value
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flower
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flower
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flower
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flower
        image: myimage
        command: ["celery", "flower", "-A", "wsgi.celery"]
        env: *defaultenv
```

But it seems like `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` won't work with YAML anchors.

```
error: error parsing deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: unknown anchor 'defaultenv' referenced
```

Is it possible to use YAML anchors or is there another preferred approach of how to reuse repeating blocks for k8s configuration?

Comment: This looks like a simple typo.  Your anchor is defined as `&default` but you're accessing it as `*defaultenv`.

Comment: This works for me.  I just asked this question (incorrectly?) over on SO, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75675324/500902.  Actually I'm not sure - its a  different use.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work - even if they are in the same FILE (separated by `---`), they are different YAML docs, which don't allow anchors to span.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

YAML anchors are supported, but only for the same YAML file. You can't create the anchor (`&`) on a deployment file and reference (`*`) the value on another one.

If you want to share ENVs values across multiple Deployments, you can create a ConfigMap with the ENVs and use the [`envFrom`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables) spec. Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  FIRST_ENV: my-value
  SECOND_ENV: another-value
---  
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: beat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: beat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: beat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: beat
        image: myimage
        command: ["celery", "-A", "wsgi.celery", "beat"]
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: my-configmap
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flower
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flower
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flower
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flower
        image: myimage
        command: ["celery", "flower", "-A", "wsgi.celery"]
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: my-configmap
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to use helm and create a chart. Helm practically generates your manifests based on templates.